# How would you upload a file through mocha/chai for testing?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm using the method where the client sends a request to the server to upload a file to an s3 bucket, and then the server sends back a signed request to allow the client to do this. I'm following this tutorial -

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

Does anyone know how I can write an API endpoint test for this? I'm not doing the client side code since it's an iPhone app but I still want to test my endpoint in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a code like that, from your link :

```
app.get('/sign-s3', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  });
});
```

I would do a unit test, as a full integration test will depend on your aws account on your test env. For that I would mock `req` and `s3.getSignedUrl` and test that `getSignedUrl` is called with the correct parameters. I would also add a test, still with mock, to be sure a correct json is returned.